# Good way to slice a numpy array based on the shape of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Take two arrays of arbitrary shape, but where each of the dimensions of the second is less than or equal to the dimensions of the first.  For example:

```
np.random.seed(8675309)
a = np.random.choice(10, 3**3).reshape(3,3,3)
b = np.zeros(2**3).reshape(2,2,2)
```

What I want is the following:

```
c = a[:b.shape[0], :b.shape[1], :b.shape[2]]
```

but for an array `b` with arbitrary shape, potentially with fewer dimensions.  How could I do this programmatically?  Such that

```
def reference_slicer(a, b):
    ???
    return c

reference_slicer(a,b) == c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
def reference_slicer(a, b):
    index = [slice(0, dim) for dim in b.shape]
    for i in range(len(b.shape), len(a.shape)):
        index.append(slice(0,a.shape[i]))
    return a[index]

#array([[[ True,  True],
#        [ True,  True]],
#       [[ True,  True],
#        [ True,  True]]])
```

Comment: This answer now returns a FutureWarning. Maybe you want to update it?